# Struct initialized in function behaving weirdly

Tags: c, function, struct

In my project, i have created 3 different `typedef struct` types:

```
typedef struct Point 
{ 
    float x; 
    float y;
    float z;
} Point;

typedef struct Triangle 
{ 
    Point A; 
    Point B;
    Point C;
    unsigned char color[3];//RGB
} Triangle;

typedef struct Structure 
{ 
    Triangle* triangles; 
    unsigned int nt; //number of triangles in array
} Structure;
```

As you might have noticed, the type `Structure` has a dynamic sized array of `Triangle`s, so i'll also post here the memory allocation and freeing functions:

```
Structure newStructure(unsigned int nt)
{
    Structure S;
    Triangle* tri = malloc ((nt) * sizeof(Triangle));
    if (tri!=NULL) 
    {
        S.triangles = tri;
        S.nt = nt;
    }
    else S.nt = 0;
    return S;
}

void delStructure (Structure S) 
{
    if (S.triangles != NULL) free (S.triangles);
}
```

Then i wanted to make a function to add a `Triangle` to a current `Structure` using the following syntax: `S = addTriangle(T,S)`. This is what i have:

```
Structure addTriangle(Triangle T, Structure S)
{

    Structure R = newStructure(S.nt+1);
    int i=0;

    while(i++<S.nt) R[0].triangles[i] = S.triangles[i];
    R[0].triangles[S.nt] = T;

    delStructure(S); //Is this necessary?

    return R[0];
}
```

It shows no error messages when compiling, however when i use the function, the first `Triangle` on the array gets random values. 
To be more clear, if I have a `Structure S` with Triangles `T1` and `T2` in the array, and then i use `S = addTriangle(T3,S)` the result will be a `Structure` with the following array of `Triangle`s: `{T?,T2,T3}`, where `T?` has apparently random values.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(i++<S.nt) R[0].triangles[i] = S.triangles[i];
```

should be something like

```
for (i=0; i<S.nt; i++) {
    R.triangles[i] = S.triangles[i];
}
```

Currently, you skip assigning the first element of `R.triangles` and assign its second last element by reading beyond the end of `S.triangles`.  You can fix this by deferring incrementing `i` until the end of each loop.  (You could continue to do this using a `while` loop; I found a `for` loop clearer.)

Also, all use of `R[0]` can (should) be replaced by `R`.  `R` is a single structure, not an array.